# disable line numbers in helm buffers , emacs 26

Tags: helm, line-numbers

I have **emacs 26** installed and helm.

I would like to disable line numbers in helm buffers ( and other buffers that has no use of line numbers)

[image]

is there anyway to disable the native line number in those buffers or even better disable it in everything except buffers that has code ( buffers with filenames ) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To only enable line numbers in "buffers that have code", you could add a hook to prog-mode-hook:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'display-line-numbers-mode)
```

(or whatever line numbering mode/function you're using), and make sure you don't have `global-display-line-numbers-mode` somewhere in your init. However, "buffers with filenames" and "buffers with code" don't mean the same thing - only buffers with `prog-mode` derived major modes (which includes most major language modes) will get line numbers with this method.

You could add `display-line-numbers-mode` to something like `find-file-hook` to have it turned on whenever a file is visited.